# Promises using Polymer

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I am in the process of extending this great element by Eric: https://github.com/ebidel/geo-location

One of the features that I have added is that I execute a polymer-ajax request based on the returned lat and lng values, something alone the lines of:

`<polymer-ajax auto handleAs="json" response="{{data}}" url="http://service/?latlng={{latitude}},{{longitude}}></polymer-ajax>`

which returns some data. At the moment there are two requests going out to this service, one fails (as there are no lat & lng values passed into it) and the second one succeeds.

How can I force my ajax call to wait until the lat and lng values exists? (henceforth the promises like behaviour question)

Comment: Not sure what this has with promises and you also haven't included the relevant part of your code. You can simply check if there are lat/lang values before making the request.

Comment: Set the `polymer-ajax`'s `auto` property to false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend away!

Without seeing code, I suspect what's happening here is that `<polymer-ajax>` gets the URL, but it's of course incomplete. This still fires the element's internal `urlChanged` handler. Since you have `auto`, the request is made with bogus values.

I'd take off `auto` as Ben suggested and use the event geo-location fires:

```
<geo-location latitude"{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" on-geo-response="{{onLatLng}}"></geo-location>
<polymer-ajax id="ajax" handleAs="json" response="{{data}}" url="http://service/?latlng={{latitude}},{{longitude}}></polymer-ajax>
```

and handle the event:

```
onLatLng: function() {
  this.$.ajax.go();
}
```

BTW, please use `<core-ajax>` instead. The core-* elements are the elements we'll be supporting moving forward.

github.com/polymer/core-ajax

Comment: yes sir, yes! :-) I send you a quick note on twitter once the element is ready-ish. thanks for the quick reply.